# How to put a lock on the function?

Tags: sql-server

Because SQL Server doesn't allow to create temporary functions, is there any way to create a function, put a lock on it and keep this lock until the end of the current session?

EDIT:

I have a network database with many users. When new user connects to the database, the unique `ConnectionId` is obtained and assigned to this users' session. During a session user creates db objects such a functions (which can be treated as temporary) for a viewing purposes. For example, user A (with connectionId 1) wants to see a parameter X and user B (with connectionId 2) wants to see a parameter Y. So user A creates a function `SelectParameterFromHugeTable_1` and user B creates a function `SelectParameterFromHugeTable_2`.

My goal is to keep a function `SelectParameterFromHugeTable_1` until user A will end his session. I try to clear all the temp tables during application start, so I need to lock functions are currently in use.

Comment: Yes, it looks like what I need. Thank you! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe it would be better / less invasive to create a new shema (with restricted access) and put your function into this shema..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is with a session-level [application  lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql). This allows you to use `sp_getapplock` to leverage SQL Server locking mechanisms to manage locks on the resource name of your choosing.

With a session level lock, the lock will automatically be released when the connection is closed, or you  can release it beforehand using `sp_releaseapplock`.